# Set a proxy in pfsense

Tags: proxy, pfsense

I am trying to run pfsense on my virtualbox here I am using nat network adapter and internal network.

I have a pfsense on vm1 and ubuntu desktop in vm2 for vm1 pfsense my first adapter is nat and second is internal network and on vm2 I have internal network I can access pfesne url like 192.68.1.1 from vm to ubuntu.

Here my question is suppose I have a proxy server hosted on cloud whose ip is 100.233.44.55:3128. Can I redirect all traffic from vm2 to use this proxy. How can I configure 100.233.44.55:3128 this proxy on pfsense. Whenever someone on vm2 try to access google.com it should use 100.233.44.55:3128 this proxy is it possible to set global proxy on pfsense if yes then how.